# Error in installing plugin for Phonegap 3.1 (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to create a new project, following:

```
$ phonegap create test com.temp testX
$ cd test
$ phonegap build ios
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

The plugin (device) is successfully downloaded to `test/plugins/`, but not successfully install to `test/platforms/ios/testX/Plugins/`. Opening the project in Xcode will show those files are missing. Manually copy and reference them won't completely fix it.

What is the cause of this?

PS: It works if I dont specify the project's name:

```
//project name will be HelloWorld.xcodeproj
$ phonegap create test
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the plugin before you build iOS by switching the order of your last 2 commands

Answer (score 1):

Hi "git" is also a node module. Simplest way want i found is.

npm install -g git

This will install git in you node source location as a module.

Restart the machine.

Install phonegap plugin:
C:\Users\user1\yourprojectname>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git

You will get response as:
Fetching plugin from "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-cam
era.git"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.camera" for android
Preparing android project
org.apache.cordova.camera installed on android.

Hope this will be very helpful. If any issue reply.

Comment: The issue I had was particularly with v3.1 of Phonegap. I don't get this issue anymore with the current version(v3.3). So I can't test it anymore, but I doubt if it because of `git` since I had it long before. However, I will upvote this for your courtesy answer.